# Lorentz force acting on in one axis

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

For this case:

[image]

The two wires will experience a Lorentz force that will pull them towards one another(i.e attraction) from the countless examples, it's due to the magnetic fields of each wire "interacting" with the currents of each wire. However, beyond that can there be another electro-magnetic force?

If we introduced an exterior contact force $F_c$ that will move one of the wires($\pm z$ or $\pm y$) can there be a force that resist it?

Different view:

[image]

In other words, if one of the wires were to move in a different axis different than the one where the Lorentz force exists(in case of the initial diagram( within $x$) can it do so freely?

Comment: I can answer the 1st part but I don't get what you are trying to say in 2nd question

Comment: @Shashaank edited the question, to keep the first part only. I couldn't ask the second one correctly

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean, but note that if you start to move a wire, the velocity of the charges in it will be changed and so the force acting on them will in general change, in particular the direction of the force may change.

Answer (score -1):

There are two equal forces which act relative to each other and there is no net force generated...